# Ошибка при чтении csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

Я пытаюсь записать в объект data данные из csv файла:

```
(data =pd.read_csv("book.csv", ',',index_col='ID'))
```

Но в ответ мне приходит такая куча ошибок:

```
ValueError    Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-6aeec748f027> in <module>()
----> 1 data = pd.read_csv("book.csv", ',',index_col='ID')

C:\Users\tj\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, dialect, compression, doublequote, escapechar, quotechar, quoting, skipinitialspace, lineterminator, header, index_col, names, prefix, skiprows, skipfooter, skip_footer, na_values, true_values, false_values, delimiter, converters, dtype, usecols, engine, delim_whitespace, as_recarray, na_filter, compact_ints, use_unsigned, low_memory, buffer_lines, warn_bad_lines, error_bad_lines, keep_default_na, thousands, comment, decimal, parse_dates, keep_date_col, dayfirst, date_parser, memory_map, float_precision, nrows, iterator, chunksize, verbose, encoding, squeeze, mangle_dupe_cols, tupleize_cols, infer_datetime_format, skip_blank_lines)
496                     skip_blank_lines=skip_blank_lines)
497 
--> 498         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
499 
500     parser_f.__name__ = name

C:\Users\tj\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
283         return parser
284 
--> 285     return parser.read()
286 
287 _parser_defaults = {

C:\Users\tj\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in read(self, nrows)
745                 raise ValueError('skip_footer not supported for iteration')
746 
--> 747         ret = self._engine.read(nrows)
748 
749         if self.options.get('as_recarray'):

C:\Users\tj\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in read(self, nrows)
  1259 
  1260             names, data = self._do_date_conversions(names, data)
  ->      1261             index, names = self._make_index(data, alldata, names)
  1262 
  1263         # maybe create a mi on the columns

C:\Users\tj\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in _make_index(self, data, alldata, columns, indexnamerow)
917 
918         elif not self._has_complex_date_col:
--> 919             index = self._get_simple_index(alldata, columns)
920             index = self._agg_index(index)
921 

C:\Users\tj\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in _get_simple_index(self, data, columns)
951         index = []
952         for idx in self.index_col:
--> 953             i = ix(idx)
954             to_remove.append(i)
955             index.append(data[i])

C:\Users\tj\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in ix(col)
945             if not isinstance(col, compat.string_types):
946                 return col
--> 947             raise ValueError('Index %s invalid' % col)
948         index = None
949 

ValueError: Index ID invalid
```

Думаю, это какая-то ошибка в самом csv файле, потому что на других файлах работает нормально.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Смотрите, ваш код: `(data =pd.read_csv("book.csv", ',',index_col='ID'))`

И ошибка: `ValueError: Index ID invalid`. И там, и там упоминатся **ID**.

Проверьте `book.csv`.